# Where are user created accelerators (shortcuts) in ArcGIS Pro 2.8 saved?

Tags: arcgis-pro, configuration, shortcuts

I am trying to share some of my personal accelerators with my colleagues, and it would be useful if I could share a .config file or something similar with them instead of having to type it up in a document.

Are user defined (or global, for that matter) shortcuts saved somewhere locally?

I was looking around in the "user.config" file in roaming\Esri\strongname, but could only find my quick access toolbar configuration, but not shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [supported workflow would be to export](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/customize-the-ribbon.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_D41907B2242044388D519B5296240B74) a `.proExportedUI` file and pass this to your colleague for them to import. Inspecting the file shows the personal accelerators have been saved.

Alternatively, the accelerators seem to be saved to: `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\ESRI\ArcGISSettings.xml`. Inside you'll find

```
  <accelerators>
    <insertAccelerator refID="esri_mapping_addDataButton" flags="Ctrl" key="D0" />
  </accelerators>
```

(untested) You should be able to pass this file to your colleagues. However, if they overwrite, they'll possibly lose any settings/properties/configuration. So the best way would be to use the proper export/import.